# В каком падеже пишется количественное числительное со словом "достаточно''?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, числительные

*Два  фунта  сыра  было  нам  достаточно*  или  *двух  фунтов  сыра  было  нам  достаточно*?

Answer (score 1):

В родительном: ***двух фунтов*** сыра было нам достаточно.

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE)

> **ДОСТАТОЧНО. I. *нареч.* 1.** к Достаточный (1 зн.). *В доме всего д. Нам д. своих яблок. Корма для животных д. // (с инф. и союзом чтобы).*
>   Стоит только (что-то сделать). *Д. лишь раз взглянуть, чтобы понять,
>   как он одинок. Д. быть просто добрым человеком, чтобы помогать
>   другим.* **2.** *Разг.* В значительной степени. *Д. умён. За эти годы
>   он д. постарел.* **3. *в функц. сказ.*** Столько, сколько нужно,
>   сколько требуется для чего-л. *Сил у него д. У нас д. времени для
>   беседы. Этих денег нам вполне д.* **4.** *чего и с инф.* **в функц.
>   сказ.** Хватит, довольно, всё, конец, кончено (обычно в значении
>   просьбы или приказания). *Д. болтовни! Замолчи! С меня д.!* (о желании
>   прекратить что-л.). **II. *в зн. межд.*** Выражает желание прекратить
>   какое-л. действие, процесс и т. п.; довольно, хватит, всё, конец. *Не
>   наливай больше, д.!*

Какое значение ни возьми, везде р. п.

Answer (score 0):

***Двух фунтов*** сыра было нам достаточно.

Безличное предложение, управление Р.п.

ДОСТАТОЧНО.  **3. в функц. сказ.** Столько, сколько нужно, сколько требуется для чего-л. Сил у него д. У нас д. времени для беседы. Этих денег нам вполне д.